# Python JSON for loop only returns last record

Tags: python, json

Python parsing JSON file that is a list with an embedded dictionary
I can get the values from it but only for the last record in the dictionary

Code is attached on what I've tried

```
import json

access_json = open('shortdocuments.json', 'r')
read_content = json.load(access_json)
# Make list a dictionary
for question_access in read_content:
    print(type(question_access))

replies_access = question_access['Attachment']


for i in replies_access:
    print(i,"|",replies_access[i])
```

Wanting out put like this for all records

```
CreateDate | 2019-10-16T09:13:33

Description |
CreateUserID | 1

Path | 201910\10489_AParker_T0231056_13.pdf

Name | 10489_AParker_T0231056_13
FileID | 765

IsDepotUsed | True

Extension | .pdf

UpdateDate | 2019-10-16T09:13:33

UpdateUserID | 1
```

My JSON FIle

```
[
  {
    "UserDefinedValueID": 872,
    "UserDefinedFieldID": 56,
    "ParentID": 355,
    "Name": "PDM_Application",
    "Value": "763",
    "UpdateDate": "2019-10-27T14:29:18",
    "FieldType": "File",
    "Attachment": {
      "FileID": 763,
      "Name": "03981-00117",
      "Description": "",
      "IsDepotUsed": true,
      "Path": "201910\\03981-00117.pdf",
      "Extension": ".pdf",
      "CreateDate": "2019-10-16T09:13:32",
      "UpdateDate": "2019-10-27T14:29:18",
      "CreateUserID": 1,
      "UpdateUserID": 1
    },
    "UpdateUserID": 1,
    "CreateUserID": 1  },
  {
    "UserDefinedValueID": 873,
    "UserDefinedFieldID": 57,
    "ParentID": 355,
    "Name": "PDM_LeaseDoc",
    "Value": "764",
    "UpdateDate": "2019-10-16T09:13:33",
    "FieldType": "File",
    "Attachment": {
      "FileID": 764,
      "Name": "09658-00060_t0007192_Application",
      "Description": "",
      "IsDepotUsed": true,
      "Path": "201910\\09658-00060_t0007192_Application.pdf",
      "Extension": ".pdf",
      "CreateDate": "2019-10-16T09:13:33",
      "UpdateDate": "2019-10-16T09:13:33",
      "CreateUserID": 1,
      "UpdateUserID": 1
    },
    "UpdateUserID": 1,
    "CreateUserID": 1  },
  {
    "UserDefinedValueID": 875,
    "UserDefinedFieldID": 59,
    "ParentID": 355,
    "Name": "PDM_FAS/SODA",
    "Value": "765",
    "UpdateDate": "2019-10-16T09:13:33",
    "FieldType": "File",
    "Attachment": {
      "FileID": 765,
      "Name": "10489_AParker_T0231056_13",
      "Description": "",
      "IsDepotUsed": true,
      "Path": "201910\\10489_AParker_T0231056_13.pdf",
      "Extension": ".pdf",
      "CreateDate": "2019-10-16T09:13:33",
      "UpdateDate": "2019-10-16T09:13:33",
      "CreateUserID": 1,
      "UpdateUserID": 1
    },
    "UpdateUserID": 1,
    "CreateUserID": 1 
 }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following a for-loop, the variable that you used is still in scope.

```
for question_access in read_content:
    print(type(question_access))

# question_access is still in scope, and the last item in the list
replies_access = question_access['Attachment']
```

You need to indent the code under the loop to get each item acted upon

```
for question_access in read_content:
    replies_access = question_access['Attachment']
    for i in replies_access:
        print(i,"|",replies_access[i])
```

Edit: If you want a CSV type format, you can try this

```
import json

with open('shortdocuments.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

if data:
    i = iter(data)
    a = next(i)['Attachment']
    print('|'.join(a.keys()))  # comment line to get only values
    while True:
        try:
            print('|'.join(map(str, a.values())))
            a = next(i)['Attachment']
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

Outputs

```
CreateDate|CreateUserID|Description|Extension|FileID|IsDepotUsed|Name|Path|UpdateDate|UpdateUserID
2019-10-16T09:13:32|1||.pdf|763|True|03981-00117|201910\03981-00117.pdf|2019-10-27T14:29:18|1
2019-10-16T09:13:33|1||.pdf|764|True|09658-00060_t0007192_Application|201910\09658-00060_t0007192_Application.pdf|2019-10-16T09:13:33|1
2019-10-16T09:13:33|1||.pdf|765|True|10489_AParker_T0231056_13|201910\10489_AParker_T0231056_13.pdf|2019-10-16T09:13:33|1
```

Or using pandas

```
import json
from pandas import DataFrame

with open('shortdocuments.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    attachments = [d['Attachment'] for d in data]
    print(DataFrame.from_dict(attachments).to_csv(sep='|', index=False))
```

Comment: Oh geez - big mistake there    Thanks a ton!

Comment: I added check mark for you -- on a side note - is there a way to get the print statement to print i into 1 value vs having a line feed after each one   for example  File ID|764|UpdateUserID|1|Description| etc

Comment: you can disregard that - I figured that out - thanks again

Comment: oops thought I did - I want each record to be on one line  so 12 key/pairs per line then line feed - so in my sample above I want 3 lines total

Comment: `print(i,"|",replies_access[i], end=" | ")` would print on the same line with a delimiter.

Comment: Although, that is an odd format to read... Are you sure you don't want a CSV-like file with headers?

Comment: Ultimately yes I'm going to do csv with this - with this output resulting in 3 lines

Comment: only problem with that is I need them in same order each time - can sort be used on this?

Comment: If the JSON keys are in the same order within the objects, then the output should be in the same order, but I also added Pandas example which should take care of that

Comment: Thanks!! I tried originally to get this to work for pandas and I got close - I truly appreciate the help